# A finite group $G$ contains a subgroup $H \approx C_p \times C_p $ and a subgroup $K \approx C_{p^2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

**A finite group $G$ contains a subgroup $H \approx C_p \times C_p $ and a subgroup $K \approx C_{p^2}$ show that $p^3 | |G|$.**

From the problem we know that $G$ contains elements of order $p$ and at least an element of order $p^2$, since $K$ is cyclic. Also as we can see $H$ is Abelian.

So from this I know that $|G| = p^{\alpha} m$ , where $\alpha \ge 2$.

Also I'm not sure if this is correct but $H \cap K = {1}$ or how this can help me with proving what I need.

Comment: otherwise they would be Sylow  subgroups hence should be conjugate but all conjugates of cyclic groups are necessarily  cyclic groups

Comment: @AliTaghavi It makes sense now, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You are wellcome!

Comment: If $p^2$ is the greatest power of $p$ dividing $|G|$ then both $H$ and $K$ would be $Syl_p (G)$.

Comment: @RobArthan What proof do you have in mind that doesn't use Sylow?

Comment: @AliTaghavi - you should provide that as an answer

Comment: @AliTaghavi: I get it now.  I didn't understand what you meant by "Otherwise" and thought you were supporting the OP's claim that $H \cap K = 1$ (which isn't true, e.g., when $G = C_p \times C_{p^2}$). What you are saying is that if $p^3 \not\mid |G|$, then $H$ and $K$ would be $p$-Sylow subgroups and hence conjugate, which is impossible because they are not isomorphic).

Comment: @RobArthan Thank you for your comment. May be a generalization can be the following: let an infinit group $G$ has two subgroups $C_p\times C_p$ and $C_{p^2}$.Does $G$ necessarily has a subgroup of order $p^3$?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor thank you for your comment. I am doing so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $p^3 \nmid |G|$ then $C_{p^2}$ and $C_p\times C_p$ would be Sylow subgroups of $G$. On the other hand every two Sylow subgroups must be conjugate to each other. This is a contradiction since every two conjugate subgroups are necessarily isomorphic groups.